# MySQL JOIN based on sortorder field

Tags: mysql, join

I have a database with several `users` that each can have several `books`.

I want to get a list of users and their first book based on the (Integer) `sortorder` field in the table `book`.

Below is a example of the SQL I use now. Only problem is that it does not return the first book based on the `sortorder` field for each user.

```
SELECT
    b.id, b.user_id, b.sortorder, b.title
FROM
    books AS b
JOIN
    books_categories AS bc
ON
    (b.id =  bc.book_id)
JOIN
    categories AS c
ON
    (c.id =  bc.category_id)
JOIN
    users AS u
ON
    (u.id =  b.user_id)
GROUP BY
    b.user_id
```

Comment: Does the sortorder column always start from 1?

Comment: Well no. Can be 1, 10, 14 or something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join to a subquery that selects the first book for each user.

```
SELECT b.id, b.user_id, b.sortorder, b.title
FROM books b
JOIN (
    SELECT b2.user_id, min(b2.sortorder) sortorder
    FROM books b2
    GROUP BY b2.user_id
) first_books USING (user_id, sortorder);
```

Comment: Is first_books a field that will be returned along with b.id, b.user_id, b.sortorder, b.title?

Comment: It's just a table alias for the subquery.